# Windows 7 RC Optimizations for Netbook

Tags: windows-7, optimization, laptop

I am installing Windows 7 RC on a Dell Mini 9 (netbook) and wanted to know what the community suggested for tweaks and optimzations that I could configure to ensure the OS performed well on the scaled down hardware.

Comment: isn't system optimisation by definition sysadmin related?

Comment: That is certainly what I thought, I guess it's not optimizing a server OS on server hardware, but it is optimizing an OS on a particular type of hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would disable the Shadow Copy service since that can cause a lot of disk IO. But this is only available on certain SKUs of Windows 7.

But then again, I've been running Window 7 on a netbook for months without doing any optimizations. It's plenty optimized out of the box :-)

Comment: I thought that Shadow Copy existed in all versions of Vista and Win7 (used by the OS for restore points, forex), it just isn't available for use by user except in some versions.